# how to access session in integration test in grails?

Tags: testing, grails, integration

In my project, i set session.loggedInUser in login controller. But during integration test , we dont use login controller. So i have set value for session.loggedInUser. But i couldn't use session in that place. How can i use session in integration Test. Give some solution for this. thank you in advance

```
class MaritalStatusIntegrationTests {

    @Test
    void testCategoryAudit() {

        RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().session.loggedInUser="Anantha"
            def category = new Category(name:"Single")

        category.save(flush:true)
        assert CategoryAudit.count() == 1

        category.name="Married"
        category.save(flush:true)
        assert CategoryAudit.count() == 2
    }
}
```

Category.groovy:

```
class Category {
    static constraints = {
        name blank:false
    }
    String name

    //Auditing
    static auditable = false
    def onSave = {
        new CategoryAudit(this,'Insert').save(failOnError:true)
    }
}
```

CategoryAudit.groovy:

```
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder
class CategoryAudit {
    String name
    String operation
    String doneBy
    Date txnDate
    def CategoryAudit(){}
    def CategoryAudit(Category category , String operation) {
        this.name = category.name
        this.operation = operation
        this.doneBy = RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().session.loggedInUser
        this.txnDate = new Date()
    }
}
```

Comment: `RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().session` should work, what's the error that you're getting?

Comment: No such property: RequestContextHolder for class: com.vasco.gs.MaritalStatusIntegrationTest. After import Its working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> No such property: RequestContextHolder for class:
>   com.vasco.gs.MaritalStatusIntegrationTest.

Just to clean up, according to the OP, it was missing the import for `RequestContextHolder`.